# Why does preview-latex not show some equations?

Tags: auctex, preview-latex

I open a LaTeX file in Emacs, and press `C-c C-p C-b` (`M-x preview-buffer`) to generate math/graphics previews for the entire buffer. I find that a PDF file is generated with each page containing a math formula.

I then move cursor to the beginning of an equation, press `C-c C-p C-p` (`M-x preview-at-point`), but the equation gets folded up!  Here are screenshots before and after pressing `C-c C-p C-p`:

[image]

[image]

Am I using preview-latex correctly? Why is there no equation rendered for the first line?

When moving cursor inside an align environment, I don't get a preview either, and it says:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
Preview-PDF2DSC exited abnormally with code 1 at Sun Sep 28 10:19:53
PDF2DSC sentinel: Opening input file: no such file or directory,  ./_region_.prv/tmp19610wh0/preview.dsc
```

I installed AucTeX and TeXLive on my Ubuntu 12.04.

- TeXlive 2009-15
- AUCTeX 11.86-2ubuntu1
- preview-latex 11.86-2ubuntu1

I use `TeX-PDF-mode`.

---

After installing the latest auctex, the problem solved.

However, when C-c C_p C-d, there is an error at the end:

```
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/share/texmf-texlive/f
onts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/
public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb></usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/public/amsf
onts/cm/cmmi12.pfb></usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmm
i6.pfb></usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi8.pfb></usr
/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/share/texmf
-texlive/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr6.pfb></usr/share/texmf-texlive/font
s/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb></usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/publi
c/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb></usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/
cm/cmsy6.pfb></usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy8.pfb
></usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm10.pfb>
Output written on hw.pdf (135 pages, 204905 bytes).
Transcript written on hw.log.

Preview-LaTeX exited as expected with code 1 at Sun Sep 28 17:21:07
LaTeX: LaTeX found no preview images
```

When C-c C-p C-p, I can see the preview:

```
Preview-LaTeX exited as expected with code 1 at Sun Sep 28 17:22:06
Running `Preview-PDF2DSC' with ``pdf2dsc _region_.pdf _region_.prv/tmp32202-vH/preview.dsc''

Preview-PDF2DSC finished at Sun Sep 28 17:22:07
Running `Preview-Ghostscript' with ``gs -dOutputFile\=\(_region_.prv/tmp32202-vH/pr1-\%d.png\) -q -dDELAYSAFER -dNOPAUSE -DNOPLATFONTS -dPrinted -dTextAlphaBits\=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits\=4 -sDEVICE\=png16m -r96x96.0504''

Preview-Ghostscript finished at Sun Sep 28 17:22:21
```

Comment: The red icons usually imply that emacs cannot render the images. Check and customize the variable `preview-image-type` by `M-x customize-variable preview-image-type` and set it to `pnm` and try previews again. Also it might help to give details about your OS and auctex version.

Comment: Please edit your question and include information about how you installed LaTeX and AUCTeX.

Comment: @Vamsi: thanks. I changed that from png to pnm, but it still does not work

Comment: @lunaryorn: yes, just added.

Comment: @Tim And your Emacs version?

Comment: @lunaryorn: I guess preview-latex doesn't work on terminal emacs, and only on gui emacs? For gui emacs, it is  `GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.10) of 2013-05-16 on komainu, modified by Debian`

Comment: @Tim Obviously.  You can't display images in a TTY.  It should work in a GUI Emacs, though, but since your environment is somewhat dated, I for my part won't be able to help you much, I guess.

Comment: @luna: what part of my environment is dated?

Comment: However, please try to move point within an `equation` environment, then press `C-c C-p C-e` to generate the preview for that environment, and then `C-c C-l` to view the log buffer for the preview compilation.  Add its contents to your question.

Comment: @Tim Uhm, almost everything.  Texlive 2009 is quite old (2014 is current), and Emacs 23 is old, too.

Comment: added. @lunaryorn

Comment: Could you check your ghostscript version too ? Recent versions of ghostscript (> 9.0) do not play well with older versions of auctex. You can try to use auctex 11.87 instead of one installed by ubuntu.

Comment: @Vamsi: I just installed the latest emacs and auctex, now I can see the preview. But C-c C-p C-d says there is some error "LaTeX: LaTeX found no preview images". But C-c C-p C-p can show the preview. What does the error mean?

Comment: I am only guessing here but have you made sure to remove the older version of auctex installed by ubuntu ? That can cause a conflict.

Comment: @Vamsi Same "LaTeX: LaTeX found no preview images", after uninstalling the auctex installed by Ubuntu's software center.

Comment: Preview-latex should create a log buffer called `*your-file-name output*`. Try going through that buffer and see what happens differently for `C-c C-p C-d`  and `C-c C-p C-p`.

Comment: @Vamsi: Thanks. I added the output to my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17489/discussion-between-vamsi-and-tim).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auctex 11.86 has known issues with Ghostscript ver >=9.0. Either downgrading ghostscript or updating Auctex will fix the issue.